# How to index a boolean @Field in Hibernate Search if the field is not in the db table

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I have a problem with indexing the boolean @field in Hibernate Search, the problem is when the object has changed the rest of the fields are changed as well only the boolean field keeps the old state of the object.

```
@JsonIgnore
@Field(name = "isWarning", index = Index.YES)
@SortableField(forField = "isWarning")
private boolean isWarning() {
   //some logic
}
```

what is the right way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this "logic" you mention accesses other entities. You need to tell Hibernate Search that those entities are included in the entity with the `isWarning` method.

Let's say the `isWarning` method is defined in an entity called `MainEntity`, and it accesses data from another entity called `SomeOtherEntity`.

In `SomeOtherEntity`, you will have the reverse side of the association:

```
public class SomeOtherEntity {
  @ManyToOne // Or @OneToOne, or whatever
  private MainEntity mainEntity;
}
```

Just add @ContainedIn and you should be good:

```
public class SomeOtherEntity {
  @ManyToOne // Or @OneToOne, or whatever
  @ContainedIn
  private MainEntity mainEntity;
}
```

Note that, unfortunately, this can have a significant impact in terms of performance if `SomeOtherEntity` is frequently updated: Hibernate Search will not be aware of exactly *which* part of `SomeOtherEntity` is used in `MainEntity`, and thus will reindex `MainEntity` each time `SomeOtherEntity` changes, even if the changes in `SomeOtherEntity` don't affect the result of `isWarning`. A [ticket has been filed to address this issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1093), but it's still pending.

Comment: we have tried this solution but it's not working so far :), the only way works but we don't want to use it. is by forcing hibernate to reindex the obj again after saving.

Comment: I have used it many times and it worked, so you may want to investigate. Which version of Hibernate Search are you using? Maybe you're affected by https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2868 ?